# VNUML - 'brctl' command doesn't work in xterms

Tags: xterm

I have installed vnuml and bridge-utils on my machine, but am unable to run the brctl command on the xterm terminals that popup after building the simulation. I get a 'command not found' error. I am, however, able to run the brctl command on my host machine's terminal, so the package is there, only the virtual nodes created are not able to access it.

What needs to be done to make the 'brctl' command available to each of the UML terminals?

Comment: Did you try executing `/usr/sbin/brctl`

Answer (score -1):

check `/etc/hosts` configurations